# Sending the command(s) spawned by xargs to background

Tags: background, xargs, unix

I want to know how I can send the command(s) spawned by xargs to background.
For example, consider

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | xargs compress
```

I tried

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | xargs -i{} compress {} &
```

.. and as unexpected, it seems to send xargs to the background instead?

How do I make each instance of the compress command go to the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SunOS you may have a look at GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | parallel compress
```

It has the added benefit of not terminating incorrectly if the filename contains ' " or space. Adding -j+0 will make it run one compress per CPU core.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `--max-procs` / `-P` option to run xargs targets in the background. From the man page of GNU xargs version 4.2.27:

> --max-procs=max-procs, -P max-procs
>
> Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.  Use the -n  option  with  -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done.

(You may want to combine this with `-n 1` to makes sure that there is a new process for each file you want to compress)

Comment: (Hmm, just realised my answer is a duplicate of the second-half of gnarf's answer, which I didn't read after the opening comment about writing a shell script. I'll leave my answer here in case others also skim over gnarf's answer as I did)

Answer (score 8):

You could probably make a very quick shellscript to call compress.

```
#!/bin/sh 
# call it 'compbg' and chmod a+x
compress $* &
```

then

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | xargs -I{} compbg {}
```

Although I think you might be happier using this xargs argument:

```
 -P maxprocs
         Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at once.
```

This command should find / tee / compress 10 files at a time until its done, as well as returning control immediately to the calling script/shell.

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | xargs -I{} -P10 compress {} &
```

Comment: The UNIX I have ( $ uname -a
SunOS xxx 5.10 Generic_xx7xx1-06 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire ) does not have -P ( $ xargs -P
xargs: illegal option -- P
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]] )

Any other alternatives than the shell script wrapper?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find much for SunOS - although I did find this package "xjobs" which you might be able to compile... http://www.maier-komor.de/xjobs.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I want to edit all files that contain foo

grep -rl foo ./ | `xargs emacs` &

Comment: This starts an extra unnecessary subshell. It is better to use -P argument to xargs.

Answer (score 0):

On SunOS/Solaris, wrap the command in a call to sh (or other shell):

```
find . -type f  -mtime +7 | tee compressedP.list | xargs -Ifname sh -c 'compress fname &'
```

This should run the compresses in parallel without additional tools.

Comment: On Linux anyway, this backgrounding will cause xargs to immediately spawn the next process called for by the list being piped in. If there's a lot in compressedP.list, you'll run out of memory.